# Can't import PDF with mpdf

Tags: pdf, import, mpdf

everyone.

I started using mpdf on my website recently. Creating new pdfs is working fine, but i can't import existing ones. I get this error whenever i try to execute the import:

```
mPDF error: Cannot open ../folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/thisisthepdf.pdf !
```

(that is not the real path)

I included the mpdf in the php. The folder and the files are on chmod 777 and the pdfs are all version 1.4

This is the way i am trying to import.

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('../folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/thisisthepdf.pdf');
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hallo World');
$mpdf->Output();
```

I tried various ways to import i found on stackoverflow and other sites, but nothing worked. Not even the code from the official mpdf manual i am using (the one above) is working.
Trying to solve this issue for quite a while now, but i am out of ideas. I Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error message is raised because of a failing call of a simple fopen(). Which means that the PHP script simply cannot access the file.

So ensure that the path is valid by e.g. passing it to `realpath()`, as it seems to be a relative path. If this evaluates to `false` the path is simply wrong. Otherwise it is a permission issue.